# Panel changes it size in MdiContainer

Tags: c#

We're running into a small problem here which really annoys us. Let me quickly explain what we're doing:

We're creating a Windows Form, save it as .DLL and load it a MDIContainer. Seems fine, works fine, except that, if we're using a Panel as component in our Form, it changes the size.

Before:

[image]

After (in MDIContainer):

[image]

**(NOTE THE PANEL!).**

We're guessing that it's because of our Custom MDI Container. This is the code of our MDI Container:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NAMESPACE.Forms
{
    class MdiClientPanel : Panel
    {
        private Form mdiForm;
        private MdiClient ctlClient = new MdiClient();

        public MdiClientPanel()
        {
            this.ctlClient.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            base.Controls.Add(this.ctlClient);
        }

        public Form MdiForm
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.mdiForm == null)
                {
                    this.mdiForm = new Form();
                    System.Reflection.FieldInfo field = typeof(Form).GetField("ctlClient", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
                    field.SetValue(this.mdiForm, this.ctlClient);
                }
                return this.mdiForm;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way we can fix this? Thanks for helping.

//Edit:
Added bounty, because we want to know why this is so. How you can reproduce it:

1. Copy our MDIClientPanel code inside a new class in a new project
2. Create a second form, put some Controls inside it.
3. Load the form inside the MDIClient Panel.
4. Compile and look how the Size of the second form is changing.

This can be fixed if you open the second form like this:

```
SecondForm Form = new SecondForm();
Form.MdiParent = this.MdiClientPanel.mdiForm;
Form.Size.Width += 35; //THIS PART WILL FIX
Form.Size.Height += 20; //THIS PART WILL FIX IT
Form.Show();
```

But there is no way this is the only solution is it's kinda fishy...

Comment: Looks like the `Size` of your `Panel` or your `Form` is changed, not the position.

Comment: I meant it like this. Changed it.

Comment: Not clear. So, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want, that the Form doesn't change it size in the MDIContainer.

Comment: You mean your `skin selector` form size shouldn't be changed?

Comment: This just can't work.  There's a good reason that the MdiClient instance is hidden, it is a wrapper for a window that Windows itself creates.  MDI is a native Windows feature.  Hacking around this restriction with Reflection and creating your own or replacing it just can't come a good end.

Comment: Did u try modifying the property: `Panel.AutoSize` to appropriate values before adding the form to container. Also look at the `Control.InitLayout` method which u can override (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.initlayout.aspx). Search for the preoprty and method on MSDN and may be u can try out some values which help you...

Comment: It's not the panel that's resizing, it's your entire form. It is being reduced by the size of the window chrome (titlebar and borders). You should look into the SystemInformation class to retrieve the current values of the border and caption sizes for windows. (The size can vary depending on user settings).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why this is happening, is because the boundries of the panel are not set.

You should be able to over come this by one of the following ways:
1 - Dock the panel;

```
var x = new MdiClientPanel{Dock = DockStyle.Fill};
Controls.Add(x); //Add the control to the form
```

2 - Anchor the panel to all corners;

```
x.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top;
x.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right;
x.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left;
x.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom;
```

I was able to reproduce this error and correct it using the above method(s).

Anchoring (before):

[image]

Anchoring (after - resizing parent):

[image]

Dock (before):

[image]

Dock (after - resize parent):

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Some references if needed (MSDN); 
Anchor (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx )

Comment: Dock (MSDN): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have a fixed width and height at design time, it somehow does not follow your form to resize itself.

normally what we do is always to use a table layout panel (if there are more than one visible controls on the same form) and for each control, set the Dock to DockStyle.Fill. if there is only one control in the form, set the control itself to fill in to the form or the parent control (such as a tableLayoutPanel), and then set the following at either Design or behind-code:

```
pnl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

if you do want to leave some pace beside some controls, use TableLayoutPanel to have extra columns/rows with width (either fixed or in percentage). and then place the controls (like your panel) inside the cell you choose and set dockstyle to fill.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [anchoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y52cxte%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) the panel in your form. This will ensure that the panel will have equal space around it, *regardless* of the size of its parent form. Generally I prefer this over `DockStyle.Fill`.

When using the form as an MDI child, you really *want* to delegate control over its size to its MDI container. Just make sure your MDI child handles it nicely.

Comment: but anchoring does not resize itself with parent. thus i would say it really depends on your needs - whether you want the control resize it self following the parent